# Blob video url download

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql

Помогите! мне надо скачать видео одного сайта, не как не смогу кто может помочь меня очень нужен `src="blob:http://galent.am/40892662-deda-4ed6-91bf-aae10cf50fb4"`. Спасибо заранее и прошу не судите по русскому

Comment: попробуй правой кнопкой на видео и "сохранить как"

Comment: я не увидел там никакого видео, если вы про видео c ютуба то качайте через api